# What does the C function bit_get do in DES encryption?

Tags: c, function, encryption

I stumbled upon this piece of code while reading about DES encryption. I wonder what it does do exactly?

I see that it returns either 1 or 0 according to the result of the last if. I also understand that mask is in hexadecimal and equals 128 in decimal (why this particular value?). The for loop starts from 0 until pos%8, why? (I know that for example if pos=14 then 14%8=6).

```
int bit_get(const unsigned char *bits, int pos)
{
 unsigned char mask;
 int i;
 mask = 0x80;

 for (i = 0; i < (pos % 8); i++)
 mask = mask >> 1;
 return (((mask & bits[(int)(pos / 8)]) == mask) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Thank you! and have a good day :)

Comment: I wonder why the `for` loop was used rather than just `mask >>= (pos%8)`

Comment: @invariant: My guess is that this was written with some embedded (possibly 8 bit) chip and compiler that generated bad code when fed that code in mind.  Possibly by insisting on turning things into larger types (more code and more registers) or doing a function call for shifts greater than 1 or 2 (IAR for MSP430 did that, but it is 16bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets the `pos`-th bit (most significant bit = 0th) from the 8-bit char array `bits`.

Usually an `unsigned char` is 8-bit long. Therefore, the

```
bits[(int)(pos / 8)]
```

will first extract the octet that the desired bit is situated in. (`pos` = 8 × `pos/8` + `pos%8` )

Then we get the actual bit from the octet:

```
  10111010
# 01234567
```

To extract a bit, we perform `&` with a "mask". The operation `&` is performed bitwise which returns 1 if 1 is present in the same bit in both operands, 0 otherwise, e.g.

```
  10111010
& 11010001
= 10010000
```

Therefore, to extract the 0th bit, we `&` with 10000000 = 0x80, and with the 1st bit we `&` with  01000000 = 0x40 etc. The loop is to get the correct mask.

But the `&` only gives 0x80, 0x40 etc or 0, instead of 1 or 0. The final conditional

```
(mask & bits[...]) == mask) ? 1 : 0
```

performs the job to convert a nonzero mask to 1, and 0 to 0.

---

BTW, normally we would use a bit-shift operator `>>` or `<<` to compute the mask. It is both more efficient and clearer to anyone who know bit operations.

```
int bit_get(const uint8_t* bits, int pos) {
    uint8_t mask = 1 << (7 - pos % 8);
    return (bits[pos/8] & mask) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why he didn't just do `mask >> (pos % 8)` instead of the loop.

`0x80` is binary `10000000`, which means you start by masking off the most significant bit, as it's the only one with a `1`.